# Redirect to activity with preserving/creating activity stack

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I want to start activity from notification. I want to open an activity, which is successor of some other activities.

Example activities: `IntroActivity` -> `Photos` -> `SpecificPhoto`. What I want to achieve: In case user clicks on notification, I want to open `SpecificPhoto` activity. Keep in mind, that app can be running (for example `PhotosActivity` is displayed), or it can be shut down.

- I want to preserve back button functionality (move to `PhotosActivity` on back pressed).
- On notification click, I need to launch `IntroActivity`, because user needs to login here in case he is not.

I tried following (using constants in activities, `code`):

On `PhotosActivity` `onCreate`:
`redirectToActivity();`

RedirectToActivity method:

```
private void redirectToActivity() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int activityCode = intent.getIntExtra("code", 0);

    switch (activityCode) {
        case SpecificPhotoActivity.CODE:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SpecificPhotoActivity.class));
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
```

By applying this approach, I can traverse the whole activity stack and go to the activity I want. However, this approach is not working in every case. Sometimes, the `activity_code` is not set (don't know why) and therefore we end in the first activity.

Is there any more professional approach to solve this issue? I believe this must be solved somehow in many apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called [`TaskStackBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TaskStackBuilder.html).

Here's how you should construct the intent, that would navigate to `SpecificPhotoActivity`:

```
    Intent action = new Intent(context, SpecificPhotoActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(action)
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

In order to correctly specify stack of activities, you should provide `android:parentActivityName` inside manifest file:

```
<application ...>
    <activity android:name=".SpecificPhotoActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".PhotosActivity"/>
</application>
```

With this parameter you have specified, that the parent of `SpecificPhotoActivity` is `PhotoActivity`, thus `TaskStackBuilder` would understand where to navigate as soon as back button is clicked inside `SpecificPhotoActivity`.

Construction of the notification should be as follows:

```
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(...)
            .setContentText(...)
            .setSmallIcon(...)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Now notification click would open `SpecificPhotoActivity`. A click on back button would navigate to `PhotosActivity`.

What's left is authorization handling. I suppose you are able to apprehend whether user is authorized or no during the construction of the notification. Hence, following approach should work:

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
    if (authorized) {
        Intent action = new Intent(context, SpecificPhotoActivity.class);

        pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
                .addNextIntentWithParentStack(action)
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    } else {
        Intent action = new Intent(context, IntroActivity.class);
        action.putExtra("photos_flow", true);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, action, 0);
    }
```

Now, inside `IntroActivity` after successful authorization:

```
    void onAuthorized() {
        if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("photos_flow", false)) {
            // most possibly you should pass some id into SpecificPhotoActivity's intent
            Intent[] intents = new Intent[]{new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class), new Intent(this, SpecificPhotoActivity.class)};
            startActivities(intents);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I specify android:parentActivityName like you said, I need to do that for all activities in the stack chain. But if I have IntroActivity as launcher activity, it is not good idea to specify android:parentActivityName for PhotosActivity, because on back pressed I do not want to go/return from PhotosActivity to IntroActivity.

Comment: You do **not** need to specify `parentActivityName` for `PhotosActivity`, simply because you do **not** need any activity to be considered as its parent.

Comment: It's working now! The problem was that I had some flags set to intent: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); . For y'all, be careful when setting flags!